# LVS clear persistance when need to drop a server out for maintenace

Tags: lvs

I wonder if someone can quickly help me.

I have the following for LVS.

rr persistent 3600

I need to drop a server out for maintenance. I have already dropped the weight to 0. Its taking forever for the ActiveConn to drop to 0.

I would like to ask, after dropping the weight, is there a way to force or politely get the maintenance server out (I.e. clear the persistence table).

Googling shows http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.persistent_connection.html

If I read correctly I need to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/expire_nodest_conn to 1.
But Im not sure if its correct.

Thanks
Brent

Answer (score 2):

It'll take forever (possibly literally) for the active connections to drop to 0, because every time a client makes a request, it'll reset the timer that expires persistence entries.  The only way to get a realserver to drop out of persistence is to remove it from the load balancing group entirely; that'll cause all the entries for that real server to be distributed elsewhere.  Yet another demonstration of why you shouldn't use session affinity.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fail over to another node is to take out the failed real-server completely. That will cause clients in the persistent list for the failed node to change to another node.